# Istio queryParams always returning truthy

Tags: istio

Set up istio and the basic bookinfo app

set up the virtual service as such:
one with headers:

```
kind: VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
    - '*'
  gateways:
    - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - headers:
            apiKey:
              exact: test
      rewrite:
        uri: /productpage
      route:
        - destination:
            host: productpage
            port:
              number: 9080
  tcp: ~
  tls: ~
```

and another with queryParams as the routing differentiator:

```
kind: VirtualService
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
metadata:
  name: bookinfo
spec:
  hosts:
    - '*'
  gateways:
    - bookinfo-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - headers:
            apiKey:
              exact: test
      rewrite:
        uri: /productpage
      route:
        - destination:
            host: productpage
            port:
              number: 9080
  tcp: ~
  tls: ~
```

For some reason, the header policy seems to work fine. i.e if I dont submit the `header=test`, istio will return 404.

HOWEVER, for the queryParams, it is always returning thruthy. am I doing something wrong? or is this an istio related issue at its core.

(note: these 2 vs are not running in parallel, but rather an update from one to another, so it cant be some wonkyness with having 2 similar VS)

Ideally i would expect for the queryParam vs headers to act the same.

Comment: I think you need to edit the second part as no `queryParams` are shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was in fact a quasi-defect.

The docs for istio-1.2 was incorrectly stating feature that was found in 1.3.

For those of you in a similar situation, upgrading to istio 1.3.x should resolve it.