# Filtering on queryParams with Istio 1.1.6

Tags: kubernetes, istio

As was pointed out here ([Istio queryParams always returning truthy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57496077/istio-queryparams-always-returning-truthy)), matching on queryParams was only implemented in Istio 1.3. I am running a system that is currently locked to Istio 1.1.6 and have a use case where I need to be be able to match on query params. My question is, whether there is some workaround with which that can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately support for query param matching was added in v1.3 and there is no way to do this on 1.1.6. The solution here would be to upgrade your istio at least to 1.3 since version 1.1.6 seems to be a bit old.

Github pull ref: [Add support for HTTP query param matching #13730](https://github.com/istio/istio/pull/13730)

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, thanks for confirming